# When I am trying to display data using stored procedure I get error: Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE db.transaction; expected 11, got 13

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Below is the code of my stored procedure. When I run it it throws the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1318 Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE db.meet_me_licence_transaction; expected 11, got 13
>
> The SQL being executed was: CALL meet_me_licence_transaction('','','','','','','','','','','transaction_id DESC',0, 0)

```sql
    DELIMITER $$
    
    USE `fermax_crm_local_4_31`$$
    
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `meet_me_licence_transaction`$$
    
    CREATE DEFINER=`dbfermaxcrm`@`%` PROCEDURE `meet_me_licence_transaction`(
                            IN v_private_key VARCHAR(255),
                            IN v_condo_name VARCHAR(200),
                            IN v_unit_name VARCHAR(20), 
                            IN v_username VARBINARY(1000),
                            IN v_licence_number VARCHAR(255),
                            IN v_new_expiry_date DATETIME,
                            IN v_transaction_mode SMALLINT(6),
                            IN v_transaction_date DATETIME, 
                                
                            IN v_Sort TEXT,
                            IN v_limit INT, 
                            IN v_pageIndex INT)
    BEGIN
            DECLARE v_Select TEXT DEFAULT "";
            DECLARE v_Where TEXT DEFAULT " WHERE 1";
            DECLARE v_From TEXT DEFAULT "";
            DECLARE v_OrderBy TEXT DEFAULT "";
            DECLARE v_QueryLimit TEXT DEFAULT "";
            DECLARE v_group_by TEXT DEFAULT "";
            DECLARE v_having TEXT DEFAULT "";   
            SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000000;
        
            SET v_Select = CONCAT(" SELECT
                      mmlt.condo_name,
                      mmlt.unit_name,
                      u.username,
                      mmlt.licence_number,
                      mmlt.new_expiry_date,
                      mmlt.transaction_mode,
                      mmlt.transaction_amount,
                      mmlt.discount,
                      mmlt.received_amount,
                          mmlt.transaction_date               
                    ");  
            SET v_From = CONCAT(" FROM meet_me_licence_transaction AS mmlt
                        LEFT JOIN user AS u
                        ON mmlt.user_id = u.user_id ");
        
        
        IF (IFNULL(v_condo_name,'') != '') THEN
            SET v_Where = CONCAT(v_Where," AND TRIM(LOWER(mmlt.condo_name)) LIKE \"%",TRIM(LOWER(v_condo_name)),"%\" ");
         END IF;
        
         IF (IFNULL(v_unit_name,'') != '') THEN
            SET v_Where = CONCAT(v_Where," AND TRIM(LOWER(mmlt.unit_name)) LIKE \"%",TRIM(LOWER(v_unit_name)),"%\" ");
         END IF;
        
        IF (IFNULL(v_username,'') != '') THEN
            SET v_Where = CONCAT(v_Where," AND ( TRIM(LOWER(u.username)) LIKE \"%",TRIM(LOWER(v_username)),"%\"  OR TRIM(LOWER(mmlt.username)) LIKE \"%",TRIM(LOWER(v_username)),"%\" ) ");
         END IF; 
         
        IF (IFNULL(v_licence_number,'') != '') THEN  
            SET v_Where = CONCAT(v_Where," AND TRIM(LOWER(fn_decrypt(mmlt.licence_number))) LIKE \"%",TRIM(LOWER(v_licence_number)) ,"%\" ");
         END IF;
        
        IF (IFNULL(v_new_expiry_date,'') != '') THEN
            SET v_Where = CONCAT(v_Where," AND DATE(mmlt.new_expiry_date) = '",v_new_expiry_date,"' ");
        END IF;
        
        IF (v_transaction_mode != '') THEN
            SET v_Where = CONCAT(v_Where," AND lower(mmlt.transaction_mode) LIKE '%",v_transaction_mode,"%' ");
        END IF;  
    
         IF (IFNULL(v_transaction_date,'') != '') THEN
            SET v_Where = CONCAT(v_Where," AND DATE(mmlt.transaction_date) ='", v_transaction_date,"' ");
         END IF;    
        
        IF(v_Sort != "") THEN 
            SET v_OrderBy = CONCAT(" ORDER BY  ",v_Sort);
        END IF;
         
        IF (v_PageIndex) > 0 THEN
            SET v_QueryLimit = CONCAT(" LIMIT ", v_limit, "," , v_pageIndex);
        END IF;
         
         
         SET @vv_Query= CONCAT(v_Select
                    ,v_From
                    ,v_Where
                    ,v_group_by
                    ,v_OrderBy
                    ,v_QueryLimit);
               
        -- SELECT @vv_Query;
            PREPARE s1 FROM @vv_Query;
            EXECUTE s1; 
        END$$
    
    DELIMITER ;
```

**Below code is of my spCall file:-**

```
<?php
namespace backend\models;
use yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use backend\models\Payment;
use yii\data\SpDataProvider;

class PaymentSearch extends Payment
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['company_id','transaction_mode'], 'required'],
            [['created_by', 'updated_by'], 'integer'],
            [['condo_id','condo_name','unit_id','unit_name', 'transaction_mode','licence_number','user_id','username'], 'string'],
            [['transaction_amount','received_amount','discount','total_amount'], 'number'],
            [['new_expiry_date','updated_on','created_on','transaction_date'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

     public function scenarios()
    {
            return Model::scenarios();
    }

    public function search()
    {
        $arrParams = array();

        $arrParams['v_private_key']         =  '';
        $arrParams['condo_name']            =  $this->condo_name;
        $arrParams['unit_name']             =  $this->unit_name;
        $arrParams['username']              =  $this->username; 
        $arrParams['licence_number']        =  $this->licence_number; 
        $arrParams['new_expiry_date']       =  $this->new_expiry_date; 
        $arrParams['transaction_mode']      =  $this->transaction_mode;
        $arrParams['transaction_date']      =  $this->transaction_date;
            
        // print_r($this->created_on);exit();      
        $dataProvider =   new SpDataProvider([
            'spName'  =>  'meet_me_licence_transaction',
            'params'  =>  $arrParams,
                    'sort'=> [
                    'attributes' => [
                                        'transaction_id' => [
                                            'asc' => ['transaction_id' => SORT_ASC, 'transaction_id' => SORT_ASC],
                                            'desc' => ['transaction_id' => SORT_DESC, 'transaction_id' => SORT_DESC],
                                            'default' => SORT_DESC,
                                            'label' => 'Name',
                                        ],
                                    ],
                    'defaultOrder' => ['transaction_id' => SORT_DESC],
                ],  
            'pagination' => [
                  'pageSize' => 10,
             ], 
        ]);
        
        return $dataProvider;
  
    }
```

}

Comment: Where is your code that actually calls that procedure? As it's shown in the error you are getting you are clearly passing too many parameters into the procedure.

Comment: I have edited my code please check @ 
Michal Hynčica

Comment: Can you add the code of `SpDataProvider` class? Or if it's part of some 3rd party package then at least provide link to the package. I don't know what that class is and why it's in `yii\data` namespace, but it's definitively not a standard part of Yii2 framework.